# Using Google Chrome extension with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, google-chrome-extension

I have just started a project and it requires to save a bookmark from google into an active record database, however I am pretty lost how to get started does anybody have any suggestions?

So far I found this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks#method-create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... I guess that you should do the following:

1. Read the bookmarks of the user installing your extension with [chrome.bookmarks](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks) API. For instance, you will use some "get***()" functions.
2. Send the read bookmarks to your server with Ajax. If you can use jQuery, the [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is available to send them.
3. Write the Controller class of your rails application to receive the sent bookmarks. Please see the [Action Controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) document to create your controller.
4. Write the model class of your rails application to store the bookmarks. Probably, you should read the [Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) document so that you can create the model.

These steps are basic knowledge to develop a simple Web application, therefore, if you complete to the coding above, you will be able to have an ability to create many Web applications. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I was a bit lost on where to get started. This looks great.